# Getting all records from database to Vaadin Table

Tags: java, postgresql, vaadin

I'm trying to load records from database table to Vaadin table.

I'm getting all records from table `process` like this:

```
public ResultSet selectRecordsFromDbUserTable() throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String selectTableSQL = "SELECT * from process";

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        System.out.println(selectTableSQL);
        // execute select SQL stetement
         rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
    return rs;
}
```

And it is working well. In `ResultSet rs` I'm getting all rows which I need.

How to load them into Vaadin `Table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all add container properties

```
table.addContainerProperty("Id", Long.class, 1L);
table.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, "");
//......
//Add other columns for table which are container properties
```

Loop through `ResultSet`

```
int itemId=1;
while(rs.next()){
   table.addItem(new Object[]{rs.getLong("id"),rs.getString("name")},itemId++);
}
```